# How can I make Video.js work on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, video

I'm using [the Video.js framework](http://www.videojs.com/) for displaying videos on my HTML5 pages.
The videos display correctly on all desktop browsers (the latest version of each), but not on my iPhone or iPad (it doesn't show anything).

How can I make it work on them too, especially the iPad?

Comment: Considering that VideoJS won't really do much with iPad video (other than let the semantic VIDEO tag run vanilla), the real question is, what format is your video in?

Comment: i use mp4, webm and ogv formats. what format should i use ?

Comment: How did you encode the Mp4?  Mp4 encoding is far far more complex then people believe, and it is really easy to screw up the device-happiness of the format.

Try posting your embed code.  The raw HTML should be sufficient, you shouldn't need any of the JS.

Answer (score 1):

It is VERY important that you encode the mp4 file using the "Baseline" settings. I was using Adobe's Media Encoder for the mp4 file I was generating. Even though I selected a preset for Apple TV, iPad, iPod... the default profile was "Main". This did not work on my iPhone. When I re-encoded I set the Profile to "Baseline" and the Level to 3.0 and, Voila, it plays on my iPhone.